# why does 10 becomes : in c program

Tags: c, for-loop, character

```
char **array;        
char *x_ptr = &array[0][0];
int rowcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {


            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0) {
                    rowcount += 1;
                    *(x_ptr +( i*column + j)) = rowcount+'0';
                }
                else {
                    *(x_ptr +( i*column + j)) =  0;
                }

            }
     }
```

When running this loop for the for the 10th time, why does it store the int value for 10 as symbol:
Current result 
8,9,:,;,<,=,>

Comment: The source code is not correct; the variable ´row` is not defined. Anyhow, source code debugging questions are usually considered off-topic. Please revise how to use StackOverflow.

Comment: This code invokes *undefined behavior*. The initialization of `x_ptr` dereferences an indeterminate `array` pointer to pointer (twice).

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII for '0' is 48. If you add 10 to it, you'll get 58, which is the ASCII for ':'.

Comment: How to add 10 as char into the array? I tried doing a snprintf(buffer , 5,"%d, rowcount); it managed to split then value into buffer[0] and buffer[1]. But when i try to place the value into the array, the char takes it as ASCII 49+48.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use `char array[10][10];` not `char **array;`
2. ':' == '9' + 1

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row = 10, column = 10;
    char array[10][10];
    int rowcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
            if (j == 0)
                array[i][j] = ++rowcount + '0';
            else
                array[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int  j = 0; j < column; ++j)
            printf("%c\t", array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```